# Why do events stored in a separate tmc file reappear in my twincat .tsproj file?

Tags: twincat

I have a TwinCAT PLC project with events. When I first added the [event classes](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/4852757259.html&id=) they were stored in the `.tsproj` file. For [source control purposes](https://cookncode.com/twincat/2021/06/07/tc-source-control-tips.html#2-creating-independent-files) I moved these events to separate `.tmc` files. However, now whenever I switch my target system the event classes are re-added to the `.tsproj` file. The event classes are not added with a rebuild or reopening the project.

Why are these files added to the `.tsproj` again? They should not be needed here, since they are stored in the `.tmc` files. I'm using TwinCAT 4022.29.

Comment: How did you move the different event classes to separate TMC-files?

Comment: Right click on <Type System>, select Add New Item.... Give the tmc file a name and save it. Then open the tmc file you just created and go to the Event Classes tab. Then select the existing event classes you wan to save in the newly created tmc file.

Comment: You might also run into https://stackoverflow.com/q/68678539/6329629 if you're using 4022.x.

Answer (score 2):

The answer came to me when I tried to move the events into a separate `.tmc` file in a TwinCAT 4024.12 project. **It turns out you need to uncheck "Persistent (even if unused)"**, as you can see by this clear tool-tip when the check mark is still there.

[image: remove persistent mark]

To remove the "Persistent (even if unsed)", right click on the event to uncheck the option.

[image]