# Why are events moved from a twincat project file to a separate tmc file not formatted?

Tags: twincat

I have a TwinCAT PLC project with events. When I first added the [event classes](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_eventlogger/4852757259.html&id=) they were stored in the `.tsproj` file. For [source control purposes](https://cookncode.com/twincat/2021/06/07/tc-source-control-tips.html#2-creating-independent-files) I moved these events to separate `.tmc` files.

When the events are moved to the new `.tmc` file they are not formatted as they were in the `.tsproj` file. In the `.tmc` file all events are on a single line. How can I make sure TwinCAT formats the events in a more human and source control friendly way with line breaks? I'm using TwinCAT 4022.29.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade to TwinCAT 4024. Event tmc files are correctly formatted in TwinCAT 4024.12 and maybe also versions < 4024.12.

For 4022.x they are unfortunately always formatted on a single line. If you want to have them nicely formatted, you can use a formatter such as the Sublime plugin [Indent XML](https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml).