# Why are TwinCAT system events translations and data types stored in the .tsproj file when using standalone PLC project?

Tags: twincat

I converted my TwinCAT PLC project into a standalone PLC project + several "machine specific" projects for versioning purposes and since then the system events translation and the data types are stored in the machine .tsproj file :
[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwFey.png)

This is quite bad for versioning as the file changes each time I open it.

I store my customs TCEventLogger events in a separate .tmc file included in the standalone PLC project so they doesn't appear there (see also [Why do events stored in a separate tmc file reappear in my twincat .tsproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677733)). I would like the system events and the data types to be included in the standalone project but not in the machine projects, any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi EDGYNcfe, welcome to StackOverflow. Tip: you can put a `!` in front of the `[]` of image links to show the actual images in the post. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The title of the question doesn't quite match with your question, you can edit it. You want event translations, not the system events themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the title.
I can't put the image directly, it seems I need 10 reputations before being able to do that.